# Unable to inject directive as dependency in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am learning to create directives and made them available via dependency add, but somehow it is not working, let me know what I am doing wrong.

Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/Mk4h7XvSN2YA26JZZ9Ua?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="firstDirective.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
    <div class="container">
        <simple-directive></simple-directive>   
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

**firstDirective.js**

```
angular
    .module('firstdirective')
    .directive('simpleDirective', function(){
        return {
            scope: true, // inherit child scope from parent
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<h2>My first directive from dependency</h2>'
        };
    });
```

**script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['firstdirective']);
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function(){
    var vm = this;
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new module you need to pass an array of dependencies as the second argument:

```
angular.module('firstdirective', [])
```

Otherwise you are trying to retrieve the module.